# Referencing other rows when parsing select

Tags: postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I am not very savvy with SQL and I have a task with a, to me, fairly complex use case. I am migrating information from an old database format to a new, more easily decipherable domain derived format.

I have a table in the old database that I have to parse the following way:

The first row in the below table signifies when the system *enters* a state. The second row signifies when the entered state is left and transitioned to another. The state type is indicated by the state column.

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------+------+-------+
|                 uuid                 |        timestamp        |        mac        | trans_count | type | state |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------+------+-------+
| 66278266-9727-4d2c-be3f-5a84504bfb90 | 2011-09-26 08:52:57:000 | 00:60:e0:4e:5d:91 |           1 |    0 |     1 |
| 31ff112c-f11b-41c3-b5c2-08ea9e84415a | 2011-09-26 08:53:06:000 | 00:60:e0:4e:5d:91 |           2 |    0 |     0 |
| 88d671c8-8ff7-4bf3-9e58-c7ced815c454 | 2011-09-26 08:53:57:000 | 00:60:e0:4e:5d:91 |           3 |    1 |     1 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------+------+-------+
```

So, what I want to achieve, programmatically, is that these three rows should be concatenated to two:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+------+------------+
|                 uuid                 |          enter           |            exit            | mode |   state    |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+------+------------+
| 09570915-d846-48db-ba87-e36c544383bb | 2011-09-26 08:52:57:000  | 2011-09-26 08:53:06:000    | SCO  | INITIATION |
| 2a472124-8ccb-46a4-9f84-cfcdf23a13d7 | 2011-09-26 08:53:06:000  | 2011-09-26 08:53:57:000 |  | SCO  | CLOSED     |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+------+------------+
```

The first row in the table above have the *enter* time of the first row in the first table, and the *exit* time of the second row in the first. The second row in the new table have the *enter* time of the second row in the first table, and the *exit* time of the third row.

The type and state in the first table are just ordinal enums which I have translated to string representation to be able to read from the database in an easier way.

What I would like is just for a pointer to what techniques can be used. I can not touch the origin table, but I can create new tables to keep track of what I have already handled in the same database.

Is is possible to get a result set and reference next / previous elements in it? What would be the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone is interested, here's how I did it:

```
select
    ss.UUID,
    ss."date" as "enter",
    coalesce(lat."date", ss."date") as "exit",
    ss."type" as "mode",
    ss.STATE,
    scs.CUSTOMER_ID as "session_id"
from
    STAT_CUSTOMER_SESSIONS scs,
    STAT_SESSION ss
left join lateral(
        select
            "date"
        from
            STAT_SESSION ss2,
            STAT_CUSTOMER_SESSIONS scs2
        where
            ss2."date" > ss."date"
            and scs2.SESSION_ID = ss2.UUID
            and scs2.CUSTOMER_ID = scs.CUSTOMER_ID
        order by
            ss2."date" asc limit 1
    ) lat on true
where
    scs.SESSION_ID = ss.UUID
```